# Validate using jQuery based on input type = radio/checkbox/select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to validate input fields like text, email, radio, checkbox, select. Lets say I have this :

```
<fieldset>
    <div class="form-top">
         <div class="form-bottom">
              <div class="form-group">
                   <label class="sr-only" for="form-first-name">First name</label>
                   <input type="text" name="form-first-name" placeholder="First name..." class="form-first-name form-control" id="form-first-name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                   <label class="sr-only" for="form-last-name">Last name</label>
                   <input type="text" name="form-last-name" placeholder="Last name..." class="form-last-name form-control" id="form-last-name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
                   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
                   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other  
              </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                   <label class="sr-only" for="form-about-yourself">About yourself</label>
                   <textarea name="form-about-yourself" placeholder="About yourself..." class="form-about-yourself form-control" id="form-about-yourself"></textarea>
                   </div>
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-next">Next</button>
        </div>
</fieldset>
```

In jQuery I use this to validate :

```
$('.registration-form .btn-next').on('click', function() {
        var parent_fieldset = $(this).parents('fieldset');
        console.log(parent_fieldset);
        var next_step = true;

        parent_fieldset.find('input[type="text"], input[type="radio"], input[type="password"], textarea').each(function() {
            if( $(this).val() == "" ) {
                $(this).addClass('input-error');
                next_step = false;
            }
            else {
                $(this).removeClass('input-error');
            }
        });
```

The input type=text and textarea validations are working but not the input type=radio. Any Idea ?

**UPDATE 1**
I'm working on a multi step form and I use this [example](http://azmind.com/2015/05/31/multi-step-registration-form-bootstrap-css3-jquery/) and in this example I added in the first step

```
<div class="form-group">
     <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
     <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
     <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other  
</div>
```

Comment: Each radio button has value so `$(this).val()` is not empty...you have to check value of selected radio button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't check the `($this).val()` for radio you should check :

```
($this).find(":selected").text();
```

**EDIT**

One little exemple :

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  $("input[type='radio']").each(function() { 
   var radioName= $(this).attr('name'); 
    var isChecked =$("input[name='"+radioName+"']:checked").val();
    
    if( $(this).val() != "" && isChecked){ 
      $("#result").html('success');
    } 
    else { 
      $("#result").html('error');
    }  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
     <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
     <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
     <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other  
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
<input type="button" class="btn" value="send"/>
```

Comment: I tryed this `parent_fieldset.find('input[type="text"], input:radio:checked, input[type="password"], textarea').each(function() {
      if( $(this).val() == "" ) {
       $(this).addClass('input-error');
       next_step = false;
      }
      else {
       $(this).removeClass('input-error');
      }` but is not working

Comment: based on the code you provided I made some changes and it is working, I assume the checkbox and  select are the same